# Convert from ASP.NET 4.5 project to ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently doing a project in Visual Studio 2012 in ASP.NET with framework 4.5. But due to some circumstances my guide asked me to do the project in framework 2.0. Is there any way to convert the project from 4.5 framework to 2.0? I have already completed the whole project and it has many pages. So i cant do it again from first. Also im new to ASP.NET so im not sure if the syntax changes from 2.0 and 4.5. Can i convert the project to 2.0 and run it in Visual Studio 2012 itself or should i only Visual Studio 2005 or 2008? Even if i can convert and run it in Visual Studio 2012 itself, will i have to change anything in the syntax? Because i am not sure what tags and elements from 4.5 are supported in 2.0. Please help me out.

Comment: Be aware that .NET 2.0 is out of support as far as Microsoft is concerned. You really should avoid using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article [How to: Change the Target .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx)

Unfortunately if you wrote something in 4.5 and it is not available in 2.0 you should re write it. Also it is possible to have a lot of compilation errors which you should handle one by one and you need to re test your code again.

You can use VS 2012 for your project on ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: I went to properties and converted the framework mostly i get error in `<asp:Button>` and `<asp>Table>` but i can convert them to normal HTML `<input>` button and `<table>`. But problem is i have used a lot of `<asp:ScriptManager>` and `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to make refresh free postback within my page. Is there any other alternate to get this effect in framework 2.0?

Comment: @ManoUncharted I can't fix your errors here, you should research them. Also the buttons should be okay.